# WPF - Displaying thumbnails in a grid as they arrive from an external source

Tags: wpf

I recently wrote a routine that displayed a grid of images from files in a folder.   I used a vertically-oriented ListBox where each row in the ListBox was a horizontally-oriented StackPanel of the images.   I just had to walk the folder tree and populate the StackPanel. It was simple, quick and easy to implement.

Now I have a new requirement.   I'll be receiving the images one-at-a-time from a piece of factory equipment that will be sending one every few seconds and I need to display it as I get it.  I still need to display these in a grid but the images start from the lower left and proceed to the right until a row is filled up, then we start a new row directly above it.   We WILL know at the start the final dimensions, but it may be more than we can fit on a screen so scrolling will have to be enabled.

What are the right controls to use for this in WPF?   Is there a way to reuse my ListBox/StackPanel scheme or are there more appropriate controls for this?   Remember, the images must be displayed as I get them -  I can't fill up a whole StackPanel and then do a

```
listBoxImages.Items.Add(myStackPanel)
```

... or can I  -  can I add an empty StackPanel to a parent and then populate one image at a time afterwards?  What's the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact the number of images is known at the start of the routine, I would create a view model with a collection of collections.

The first is an observable collection with elements for each row, inside the element is another collection for each column. This can be bound to an items control where the content template has a second items control with horizontal orientation.

Then, as your images arrive, you start to fill the last element first with your image references and work back up. That should create the desired effect. Not sure how that works with scrolling as you effectively want the last element to be in view first, so scrolled to the end.

Another option, using a single collection is to bind to an items control with a uniform grid panel template. This can be wired up with a DataTemplateSelector which when the data is null, displays an empty template, otherwise shows an image box. This will allow you to again add elements to your collection in any order and it mirror on the UI.

An example of the data template selector can be found [here](http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector). Or search SO.